# Replicating Font Awesome duotone icons

Tags: copyright

[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) Pro has a lot of icons that are just the same as the free versions but with two colors instead of one. My question is if I manually change the free versions to look like the pro versions, is it considered copyright infringement?

Answer (score 2):

> From the US [copyright office](https://copyright%20office) -

> Typeface, Fonts, and Lettering
> Copyright law does not protect typeface or mere variations of typographical ornamentation or let- tering. A typeface is a set of letters, numbers, or other characters with repeating design elements that is intended to be used in composing text or other combinations of characters, including calligraphy. Generally, typeface, fonts, and lettering are building blocks of expression that are used to create works of authorship.

The name of a typeface can be a trademark and a program that draws the shape of a letter (called a font) can be copyright but the shape of the letter can’t be copyrighted *in the US.*

This is not true for most countries.

Answer (score 0):

It may be considered copyright infringement if the icons meet the threshold of originality for copyright protection. Some simple icons found in most modern UIs, like the volume, network, etc. don't meet the threshold. However more complex icons do.

Comment: Please reread Circular 33 of the US Copyright Office on Copyright.gov.